# Recovering lost documents from cmd moving

Tags: cmd, command-prompt, move

I was messing with the move command in Command Prompt, and I accidentally moved a file into a folder that didn't exist. When I tried 'dir', the invalid folder was listed, but it wasn't a directory, and it didn't show up under 'tree'. If I renamed the file as a .zip, it had folders within like _rels, docProps, and word, as well as [Content_Types].xml. Each folder contained several more xml files, but none had the document I had just misplaced. Is there a way to get it back or have I lost it permanently?

Comment: This zipping shows that that was a `.doc` or `.docx` document. Just to clarify - you tried to copy the file in to that document??

Comment: I moved a .docx into a file that didn't exist. It was simply a 'file' with no ending, so I renamed it with .zip on the end.

move document.docx invalidfolder, rename invalidfolder invalidfolder.zip

Comment: And then you zippd it and got all of that?

Comment: Yep. I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: 1. change the extension to .docx
2. make a backup next time BEFORE trying new things

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically what happend is that you tried to `zip` the `.docx` document, and then you got all of these folders. It simply what happens when you zip a word document.

There's nothing strange, you can just make it `.docx` again and it will be as normal.

Comment: I extracted the zipped folder, then rezipped it (making sure it had identical formatting), and it turned out to be a completely different document from a few days ago.

Comment: You shouldn't zip it or unzip it again, just rename it's extension to `.docx` again.

Comment: Adding the .docx worked on a test document I made, but it's too late for the original. Unzip, rezip, rename .docx, open entirely different document.

Comment: so after unzipping you deleted the original `.zip` file?